# How do i set double query of Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

From below query I get the data in order of `timestamp`

```
Query Users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference.child("Users").orderbychild("timestamp");
```

Now all children are ordered by time.
But how do I filter this query by `CurrentUserId`?

```
Query CurrentUser = Users.orderbychild("CurrentUserId");
```

Comment: You can't. Instead use firestore.

Comment: my database is within firebase

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For example, you could add a property like `"CurrentUserId_timestamp": "uidOfUser_timestampValue"` and order/filter on that. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase does not support multiple `orderbychild` method. What you can do is, first fetch records from Firebase with current user id

```
Query Users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference.child("Users").orderbychild("CurrentUserId");
```

Then do **timestamp** sorting at client end.